# custom a modal dialog when handle event onbeforeunload of browser

Tags: javascript

I want a custom a modal dialogue my self when handle event `onbeforeunload`, however, I have no solution for it,  is there any ways to solve it? Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to make a modal window is to actually create one with HTML/CSS, set its display to none by default and when the `onbeforeunload` event triggers, set its display to `''`. Check [this](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/obvKxm) awesome codepen for some modal windows.

Comment: But it also show the default dialog of browser ? isnt it ?

Comment: Oh, the browser integrated dialog is deprecated now and it has been removed from almost all browsers.